# pix2pix GAN with Rectangular Image Dataset

Tags: keras, tensorflow, gan, image

I am currently working on a project (for university) which translates sketches of faces to images of this person.
For implementing this, I decided to use a [pix2pix GAN architecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07004).

However, I have the issue that the dataset contains photos in the format of 200x250 pixel instead of the 256x256 pixel the [TensorFlow reference implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/pix2pix) is designed for.
The dataset is a modified version of the [CUFS dataset](http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/archive/facesketch.html) provided by my professors.

I identified the following three possibilities for managing this dataset:

- Rescaling all images to 256x256 pixel which I implemented as a first draft and which works quite okay,
- pad the images to size 256x256 pixel and accept that parts of the training effort goes towards learning pixel which will always have a value of 0,
- or to modify the architecture in order to process images of size 200x250 pixel, which was suggested by my professor.

I have implemented the first two alternatives, but I would like to also try to implement the third alternative.
However, I am kind of afraid I might break the architecture by randomly changing the dimensions of the convolution layers.
Thus, I want to ask you if you have any suggestions on how to adapt the architecture for inputs of size 200x250 pixel?

The source code is available as a [Jupyter notebook hosted on Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uw_8Hlk05Y44LGaQl6w5OvnEif9z0EF1?usp=sharing).
I also provide [a link to the dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18FrtUqott_RnXloDEneT9ICgAUJGVK92/view?usp=sharing), in case you need it.

Just for your information, I have to use TensorFlow and Keras for this project.